# Construct function with known asymptotes

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have two lines, described by

$$ f_1(x)=r_1(x-x_0)+y_0$$
$$ f_2(x)=r_2(x-x_0)+y_0$$

E.g, for $(x_0,y_0)=(1,\frac{1}{2})$, $r_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $r_2=4$ it looks like:
[image: Example]

I am looking for a function $f(x)$, with

- $f(x) \geq f_1(x) \forall x$
- $f(x) \geq f_2(x) \forall x$
- $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)-f_1(x)=0$
- $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-f_2(x)=0$
- $r_2>r_1>0$
- $f$ and $f_x$ are continuous

That is, far from $(x_0,y_0)$ it asymptotes to either $f_1$ or $f_2$, and it should always be above both function (otherwise there are four solution I guess).

I understand that this function would look a bit like the hyperbola $\frac{1}{x}$, if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are transformed such that they align with the $x$ and $y$ axis. It is not that obvious to me now how that can be achieved.

Comment: Function might be difficult as the vertical line test is not guaranteed unless one of the asymptotes is guaranteed to be of the form $x=c$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven That would mean that either $r_1=0$ or $r_2=0$, which does not make sense for my case. Suppose $r_2>r_1>0$, would this test ever be an issue?

Comment: @Semiclassical I see your point, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Would $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ be a statisfactory solution to $(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$ with $r_1 = -1, r_2 = 1$? Because if so, the rest is just a matter of translating and transforming.

Comment: @Arthur, yeah, I think that would work for me. If I can play a bit with the maximum distance between the point where the lines cross and $f$. This is basically the answer by Martigan after his update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one obvious answer:

$g(x)=f_1(x)$ for $x<\alpha$

$g(x)=f_2(x)$ for $x\geq\alpha$

with $\alpha$ being the point where $f_1$ and $f_2$ intersects.

EDIT: a hint for an answer closer to what you are looking for...

You can change the coordinates, in order to get $f_1$ and $f_2$ symmetrical with regard to the new $x'$ axis. Within this new set of coordinates, the equation of the hyperbola will take the form of $\frac{x²}{a²}-\frac{y²}{b²}=1$, with $y=\frac{b}{a}x$ and $y=-\frac{b}{a}x$ being the equation of the asymptotes in the new set of coordinates.

You then revert to your old set of coordinates and get the equation.

Comment: Your hints are helping. Any thought on which transformation would work? Apart from the obvious translation to the origin.

Comment: You rotate the axis, so that the $f_2$ function goes down and the $f_1$ up. You need to have your new $x'$ axis as the axis of symmetry for the two functions. Rotate with $X=xcos(\theta) + y sin(\theta)$ and $Y=-xsin(\theta)+ycos(\theta)$. $\theta$ you find with the $r_1$ and $r_2$ factors.

Comment: Is was thinking about (for $x_0=0$ and $y_0=0$) and then subtracting $(r_1+r_2)x/2$ from both functions?

Comment: Than I get, as per your answer, $a=2$ and $b=r_2-r_1$.

Comment: And after back transformation that works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something "fancy", and continuous or something, pick a function $g(x)$ that goes from $0$ to $1$ as $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Simple manipulations of the inverse tangent function $\arctan(x)$ or the error function $\operatorname{erf}(x) = \int_{-\infty} ^x e^{-t^2} dt$ might do the trick. Then what you do is the following:
$$
f(x) = f_1(x)(1-g(x)) + f_2(x)g(x)
$$
This will lie between the two lines, so it's not exactly what you want, but I hope it can put you on some kind of track.